# dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error

Tags: linux, dpkg

I am getting the following error when trying to install anything using apt-get install:

dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:

files list file for package 'libxcomposite-dev' is missing final newline

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Looks like file corruption. Can you inspect `/var/lib/dpkg/info/libxcomposite-dev:amd64.list` to see what's in it? It should look like a list of files.

Comment: it seems that that file was renamed to  libxcomposite-dev1:amd64.list. for some reasons the number 1 was added to the name!